# Restrict login to the active user

Tags: access-control

How can I restrict login so that only I can log into my linux machine, and only directly into the console (active user) I do not want anyone, including me, to be able to log in remotely. Are there changes I should make to /etc/security/access.conf for example? or PAM?

Newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable `ssh`

```
systemctl disable ssh
systemctl stop ssh
```

Don't touch `/etc/security/access.conf` or PAM. Look by all means, but don't change anything at all unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and how you'll fix it if it prevents you logging in at all.

Comment: Right Chris, I am not touching those files! ty.

Comment: I've done that Chris and I get this in return:
"Failed to disable unit: Unit file ssh.service does not exist."
In the journal log I see this. What does this mean? Is this a clue?:

 Nov 03 13:32:11 pac_2023 gnome-keyring-daemon[1223]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Nov 03 13:32:11 pac_2023 sh[1226]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Nov 03 13:32:11 pac_2023 sh[1226]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=gnome-keyring

Comment: Sounds like you haven't got a remote login feature installed

Comment: Try the systemctl commands but with `sshd` as the name instead of `ssh`.  Some distros use ssh.service, others sshd.service.